# How to connect Rally API (python) to the specific reports under 'Report' section

Tags: python-2.7, rally, code-rally, pyral

I have been working on developing a Rally API using python with the help of links pointed by Rally help (Pyral). My code connects well with the Rally server and pulls specific user story I want, but not the columns I am interested in. I am aiming to pull [full] specific reports with fields such as project, tags, etc. under the 'Reports' tab. I tried to find out how can I do it but didn't get direction. Also, the specific user stories I am able to pull include some weird fields like c_name, c_offer and the like. I would really appreciate if someone could help me through this. Like to connect to a specific project/workspace in Rally we have the following code where it asks the details in the manner below:
rally = Rally(server='', apikey='',workspace='',project='')
Is there any way to specify what report/columns I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most of the reports on the Reports tab are rendered by a separate Analytics 1 service outside of the standard WSAPI you've been communicating with.  Some of that data is available in WSAPI -IterationCumulativeFlowData, ReleaseCumulativeFlowData.  What data specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Hey Kyle, I should rather say I am looking for columns like tags, project, etc.I want to be able to pull the columns of my interest through reports in different releases under Reports in Rally.